# Getting all files from multiple folders Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am using Firebase Storage for my Android app and I have a root folder "Wallpapers" and multiple folders inside this folder for different categories. I need to get all the files from all these folders in a single call. I have used the following method,

```
private void loadWallpapers(){
        StorageReference listRef = firebaseStorage.getReference().child("Wallpapers");
        listRef.listAll()
                .addOnSuccessListener(listResult -> {
                    for (StorageReference prefix : listResult.getPrefixes()) {
                        prefix.listAll().addOnSuccessListener(listResult1 -> {
                            for (StorageReference item : listResult1.getItems()) {
                               // Handle data here
                            }
                        });
                    }

                })
                .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                    int i =0;
                });
    }
```

Is this the actual way of doing it, since it contains multiple listeners? Or there is a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [API provided by Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/list-files#list_all_files) to list files is *shallow* - it doesn't return files nested under the given prefix.  The API gives you both the "folders" and files of the immediate prefix.  If you want to go deeper, you'll have to make mulitple calls - one for each virtual "folder" that you want to list.

Comment: Does this work? Because this will list all the images inside "Wallpaper" folder. In my case, there are no files in this location. All images are inside the subfolders of "Wallpaper" folder.

Comment: If you really need to do get all the files in one request, consider writing backend code using the Cloud SDK, and having your client invoke that through some API endpoint. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects